# Jetpack Compose preview error "Failed to instantiate Composition Local"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack Compose preview fails to load due to a "Failed to instantiate Composition Local" error.

I've tracked down the cause of the error. When adding FirebaseAuth the error occurs regardless of how I include FirebaseAuth

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val auth: FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth

    //UI goes here
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    HabitsTheme {
        App()
    }
}
```

or

```
@Composable
fun App(auth: FirebaseAuth) {
    //UI goes here
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    val auth: FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth

    HabitsTheme {
        App(auth)
    }
}
```

I know I'm not loading FirebaseAuth correctly, but I'm at a loss at how to this should be loaded in the preview. Even removing any use of the `auth` within the component the error occurs so its not being causes with how the class is being used later one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done this initially, but here's the answer:

Create a class variable and initialise the variable when `onCreate` is triggered.

So there is no need to pass the class to the preview!

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        auth = Firebase.auth

        setContent {
            App()
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    //UI Code
}
```

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    HabitsTheme {
        App()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we use it in a composable function in a different file?